# Bootstrap grid system with tables and printing.

Tags: bootstrap-4, jsreport

I'm trying to build a printable report using Bootstrap framework, I'm using the grid system to display two tables next to each other using columns. However, despite many attempts to get the tables to display properly that did not work.

i.e using changing columns size using @media

```
@media print {
/* Your styles here */
```

}

Here is an example of the problem:

https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/SyaEz346M/1

Thanks

Comment: Is there any critical styling happening in your style.css? Because you have a typo: href and not herf. `<link rel="stylesheet" herf="style.css"> </link>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a new Bootstrap CDN with bootstrap v4.0 rather than v4.1 and it seems like it solved the problem.